# Kafka Connector - From Kafka to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I want to use Kafka-HDFS-Connector Sending Data From Kafka to Hadoop.

I have around 150B JSON records per day, Is it possible to do it with Kafka-HDFS-Connector (performance issue)?

Thanks.

Comment: How big are the records? Do you have an SLA for the period in which the messages must be transferred?

Comment: My record is around 3K, SLA of messages transfarred is around 15 min maximum

Comment: You have to transfer 150B messages within 15 minutes? Or per day?

Comment: Have you tried it yet? What issues are you having? Number of records shouldn't matter as long as you've got fast network, and those messages are distributed over partitions and you have the same number of tasks consuming those

Comment: @RobinMoffatt, I have to transfer 150B messages per day

Comment: @cricket_007 I have been tried with Spark applicaiton but I want to check another solution so I just ask if someone try it before

Comment: Yes, I've tried HDFS Connect, but not for billions of records. Whatever solution used, it'll probably be bottlenecked on network or CPU speed

Comment: So what do you think will be best solution for bilions of records?